# Is it safe to drink water in the Dominican Republic?

Tags: tap-water, dominican-republic

To add yet another question to the long list of [tap-water](/questions/tagged/tap-water), the [US CDC for the Dominican Republic](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/dominican-republic) says *Don’t Drink Tap or well water*, but there is no mention of water concerns on [gov.uk for the DR](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/dominican-republic/health). The US warning is not everywhere (e.g., according the the [CDC for the UK](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/united-kingdom) *Food and water standards in the United Kingdom are similar to those in the United States*) and [gov.uk for Mexico](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/mexico/health) says *Drink only boiled or bottled water and avoid ice in drinks.*

I am staying at an all inclusive high end resort in the DR. Avoiding drinking tap water directly should not be that hard, but ice and unwashed or unpeeled fruits and vegetables (which the CDC recommends against will be harder). I have heard rumors that some resorts use filtered water for cooking and ice.

How can I reliable determine if I need to worry about water at a resort in the DR?

Comment: If you are worried, don't drink it. However, I think a huge "high end resort" cannot afford thousands of people getting ill, so I would guess they have taken some precautions. If in doubt, ask the hotel staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from the [CDC's details page on DR](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/dominican-republic) that their concerns boil (sorry) down to two main issues, both of which you should be ok with if you've had your vaccinations - Hep A, and Typhoid.

It's worth noting that the [Australian Smart Traveller website](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/americas/caribbean/Pages/dominican_republic.aspx) has a concern about cholera as well:

> Cholera and other infectious diseases
>
> Confirmed cholera cases continue to be reported in the Dominican
>   Republic. Cholera causes diarrhoea and vomiting and can be fatal if
>   left untreated. Correct food hygiene and preparation are essential to
>   minimise the risk of contracting cholera. Water-borne, food-borne,
>   parasitic and other infectious diseases (including hepatitis,
>   filariasis, and leptospirosis) are prevalent, with serious outbreaks
>   occurring from time to time.
>
> ```
> Drink only bottled or boiled water.
> Avoid ice cubes.
> Avoid uncooked and undercooked food.
> Ensure correct food hygiene and preparation.
> ```